# Splitting a list c#

Tags: c#, list, split

Hi I'm a little bit stuck in C#. I'm new on it.
This is my problem:

I have a list made up of 63 double numbers (let's call it "big list").

I want to split this list in 6 list with the following rule:

The first list consists of the first 8 elements of the big list;
The second list goes from the 9th element of the big list to the (9+8=17th) element of the big list;
The third list goes from the 18th element of the big list to the (18+8+1=27th) element of the big list;
The fourth list goes from the 28th element of the big list to the (28+8+2=38th) element of the big list;
The fifth list goes from the 39th element of the big list to the (39+8+3=50th) element of the big list;
The sixth list goes from the 51th element of the big list to the (51+8+4=63th) element of the big list;

How can I do it? thanks a lot in advance for your help!

i've tried in this way but it gives me error "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type method group"

List listsplitted = new List();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 8; j < 8 + i + 1; j++)
            {
                Listsplitted[i] = biglist.Take[j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Search about Skip/Take methods from the IEnumerable extensions

Comment: Hi Roberto, What you tried so far? Can you please provide your attempt and where did you stuck. Also Input and expected output would be helpful for us to understand your question properly.

Comment: Something is not clear in your indexing. The 9th element of the list is in 8th position in the list so you should start counting from 8 + 8 for the second list. Or are you intentionally skipping some elements from the list?

Comment: Hi @steve yes sorry I should start counting from 8+8 for the second list. I come from Matlab therefore I always think the index starts from 1 and not 0.. sorry!

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I've tried it (see on the post) but it gives me as error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type method"

Comment: Can you use an array instead of a list? Then you can use `ArraySement` or `Span<T>`/`Memory<T>` in newer versions of the language. This will not create a copy of the data, but segment/span/memory will point to the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [GetRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_GetRange_System_Int32_System_Int32_) function:

```
List<double> part1= big_list.GetRange(0, 8);//Retrieves 8 items starting with index '0'
List<double> part2= big_list.GetRange(8, 9);//Retrieves 9 items starting with index '8'
```

Or if you don't want to give different names to all parts, you can create a list of lists:

```
List<List<double>> listoflists = new List<List<double>>();
listoflists.Add(big_list.GetRange(0, 8));//Retrieves 8 items starting with index '0'
listoflists.Add(big_list.GetRange(8, 9));//Retrieves 9 items starting with index '8'            
for(int i=0; i<listoflists.Count;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<listoflists[i].Count; j++){
        Console.Write(listoflists[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a very simple approach with the IEnumerable extensions Skip and Take

```
List<double> first = bigList.Take(8).ToList();
List<double> second = bigList.Skip(8).Take(8).ToList();
List<double> third = bigList.Skip(16).Take(9).ToList();
List<double> fourth = bigList.Skip(25).Take(10).ToList();
List<double> fifth = bigList.Skip(35).Take(11).ToList();

// The last one is without Take to get every remaining element
List<double> sixth = bigList.Skip(46).ToList();
```

Of course you should check if the indexes are correct for your requirements. These indexes doesn't skip any elements from your bigList

You can make this approach more generic with something like this

```
void Main()
{
    var bigList = GetYourBigList();

    List<Tuple<int, int>> positions = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        new Tuple<int, int>(0,8),
        new Tuple<int, int>(8,8),
        new Tuple<int, int>(16,9),
        new Tuple<int, int>(25,10),
        new Tuple<int, int>(35,11),
        new Tuple<int, int>(46,13)
    };

    List<List<int>> result = SplitTheList(bigList, positions);

    foreach (var list in result)
    {
        foreach (var temp in list)
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
    }
 }

 List<List<int>> SplitTheList(List<int> r, List<Tuple<int, int>> positions)
 {
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
    foreach(var x in positions)
       result.Add(r.Skip(x.Item1).Take(x.Item2).ToList());
    return result;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you Steve :) but what about If I want only a list but splited? I don't want 6 different lists with 6 names but 1 big list but splitted. In Matlab for example you can have a 3D list made of several list calling this as "list(:,:,x)". is it possible to create it with a for loop (maybe?)

Comment: You can have a List of List for example. A list where each element is itself a list with these internal lists containing your values. Let me show an example

Comment: To create each list you have to run through the main list from the beginning. It's inefficient.

Comment: Well, probably you are correct. But we are talking about 63 elements here

Answer (score 0):

if you are insisting on do the operation in one single for statement you can use the following code

```
const int arrSize = 6;
var splitedLists = new List<List<int>>(arrSize);

var defaultTake = 8;
var defaultSkip = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= arrSize; i++)
{
    if (i >= 3)
        defaultSkip--;

    splitedLists.Add(array.Skip(defaultSkip).Take(defaultTake + 1).ToList());

    if (i >= 2)
        defaultTake++;

    defaultSkip = defaultSkip + defaultTake + 1;
}
```

Comment: To create each list you have to run through the main list from the beginning. It's inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace the list with an array, you can do without copying the data. You can use [ArraySegment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=netframework-4.8) (or [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netstandard-2.1)/[Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netstandard-2.1) in newer versions of the language) to do this.

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 63).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();

var splitted = new List<ArraySegment<double>>();

int offset = 0;
int count = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    splitted.Add(new ArraySegment<double>(array, offset, count));
    offset += count;
    count++;
}

// see what we have
foreach (var seg in splitted)
    Console.WriteLine(seg.Offset + " " + seg.Count);

// work with segments
var segment = splitted[3];
segment[5] = 555555;

// the main array has also changed
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
```

Note that the segments do not store copies of the data, but refer to the data in the main array.